# The data frame does not reflect the conversion of NA to 0 when "0", "1" and "NA" are input in the data about the death

Tags: r

I used the replace function to convert an integer r _ death to a factor and convert NA to 0.

You can see that the display is only 0 or 1, but when you summarize again, the NA remains.

What should I do?

```r
str(df$r_death)
#> int [1:2639] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...

summary(df$r_death)
#>    Min.  1st Qu.  Median    Mean  3rd Qu.     Max.   NA's 
#>  0.0000   0.0000  0.0000  0.2676   1.0000  1.0000    1219 

df$r_death<-as.factor(df$r_death)
summary(df$r_death)
#>    0    1 NA's 
#> 1040  380 1219 

tidyr::replace_na(df$r_death,0)
#>   [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
#>  [45] 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#>  [89] 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#> [133] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

summary(df$r_death)
#>    0    1 NA's 
#> 1040  380 1219
```

Comment: `df$r_death[is.na(df$r_death)] <- 0` should fix it. If you want to use `replace_na` it should be `df %>% tidyr::replace_na(replace = list(r_death = 0))`

Comment: If you are converting to a factor, I would avoid using the direct assignment as it may produce unexpected results. Also your code is difficult to read and reproduce.  Please read this article on reproducible examples for future questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I am a super beginner, so am learning how to write more accurate and easy understandable code.

Comment: Dear Cameron. Thank you, your code work!